# Exoplayer buffering issue

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

I am trying to successfully integrate ExoPlayer in my app.
The player works perfectly, plays videos and also buffers but when I change the seek to position the video doesn't play from the buffered data rather it start the download again (player pauses the video for a while) and starts buffering again from that position.

**When I go back from current seek position it starts to download again but when I go forward from the current position everything works fine**

Comment: do you use DASH or HLS ?

Comment: i have tried with DashMediaSource and ExtractorMediaSource

Comment: Hi Karthik have you found the solution of this problem i am also have same issue